# Cannot figure out return type of Collectors.groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Similar issues have been answered before but I still wasn't able to figure out what is the problem with my grouping and averaging method.

I have tried multiple return value combinations like `Map<Long, Double>`, `Map<Long, List<Double>`, `Map<Long, Map<Long, Double>>`, `Map<Long, Map<Long, List<Double>>>` and none of those fix the error IntelliJ throws at me: 'Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context'. 
At the moment I feel like I'm just blindly guessing. So could anyone perhaps give me some insight on how to determine the correct return type? Thanks!

Method:

```
public static <T> Map<Long, Double> findAverageInEpochGroup(List<Answer> values, ToIntFunction<? super T> fn) {
    return values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Answer::getCreation_date, Collectors.averagingInt(fn)));
}
```

Answer class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class Answer {
    private int view_count;
    private int answer_count;
    private int score;
    private long creation_date;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler error I get is different, about how the method call to `collect` is not applicable for the arguments.

Your return type of `Map<Long, Double>` is correct, but what is going wrong is your `ToIntFunction<? super T>`.  When you make this method generic, you are saying that the caller has control over `T`; a caller can supply a type argument, e.g.:

```
yourInstance.<FooBar>findAverageInEpochGroupOrig(answers, Answer::getAnswer_count);
```

However, this method doesn't need to be generic.  Just take in a `ToIntFunction<? super Answer>` to operate on the `Answer` for the values of the map.  This compiles:

```
public static Map<Long, Double> findAverageInEpochGroup(List<Answer> values, ToIntFunction<? super Answer> fn) {
    return values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Answer::getCreation_date, Collectors.averagingInt(fn)));
}
```

As an aside, normal Java naming conventions specify that you would name your variable in camel case, e.g. "viewCount" instead of "view_count".  This would affect any getter and setter methods as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing the bound from `T` to `Answer` helped! Although I still don't quite get what went wrong. Does it have to do with incompatible bounds?

The field names break convention because I use them to map JSON to POJO with Spring REST consumer.